# Compare dataframe but keep the NaN cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

for example I have a dataframe:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.493212 | 0.586246 | nan | 0.589289 | nan | 0.629087 | 0.593872 |
| 1 | 0.568513 | 0.367722 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0.423369 |
| 2 | 0.70054 | 0.735529 | nan | nan | 0.494135 | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | nan | nan | 0.338822 | 0.466331 | 0.765367 | 0.83082 |
| 4 | 0.512891 | nan | 0.623782 | 0.642438 | nan | 0.541117 | 0.92981 |

If I compare it like:

```
df >= 0.5
```

The result is:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

How can I keep nan cell ?  I mean I need `0.5 > np.nan == np.nan` not `0.5 > np.nan == False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.lt(0.5).astype(int).mask(df.isna())
```

output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  1.0  0.0  NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0
```

If you want to keep the integer type:

```
out = df.lt(0.5).astype(pd.Int64Dtype()).mask(df.isna()))
```

output:

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6
0     1     0  <NA>     0  <NA>     0     0
1     0     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     1
2     0     0  <NA>  <NA>     1  <NA>  <NA>
3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     1     1     0     0
4     0  <NA>     0     0  <NA>     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with convert values to integers:

```
df = (df >= 0.5).astype(int).mask(df.isna())
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  0.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

Details:

```
print ((df >= 0.5).astype(int))
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
4  1  0  1  1  0  1  1
```

Another idea with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df[:] = np.select([df.isna(), df >= 0.5], [None, 1], default=0)
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  0.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

Btw, if need `True/False` with `NaN` is possible use [`Nullable Boolean data type`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html):

```
df = (df >= 0.5).astype(int).mask(df.isna()).astype('boolean')

print (df)
       0      1     2      3      4     5      6
0  False   True  <NA>   True   <NA>  True   True
1   True  False  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  False
2   True   True  <NA>   <NA>  False  <NA>   <NA>
3   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  False  False  True   True
4   True   <NA>  True   True   <NA>  True   True
```

Comment: @mozway - Not understand.

Comment: I thought you had a different logic (>=0.5 OR NaN), but nevermind, happy coding